# Using eid-commons and itext - programmatically sign a pdf with a valid signature

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I see some similar questions on stackoverflow, but I sadly have been unable to come to a solution. I believe I'm quite close but just missing the right steps.

I am using my Belgian EID card, which has signing certificates on it that I can use to sign a PDF.

Maven Libraries used:

```
be.fedict.commons-eid - 0.6.5
com.itextpdf - 5.5.10
org.bouncycastle - 1.55
```

Code is as follows:

```
 BeIDCardManager manager = new BeIDCardManager();

        manager.addBeIDCardEventListener(new BeIDCardEventsListener() {

       public void eIDCardInserted(CardTerminal arg0, BeIDCard arg1) {
            log.info("Inserted");
            try {
                dostuffwithmycard(arg1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
       }
```

...

```
protected static void dostuffwithmycard(BeIDCard card) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        Security.addProvider(new BeIDProvider());
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BeID");
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        PrivateKey authnPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("Authentication", null);
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        signature.initSign(authnPrivateKey);

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\Untitled.pdf");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream( "C:\\temp\\Signed.pdf");
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason("Okay");
        appearance.setLocation("Home");
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36,748,144,780), 1, "sig");

        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        ExternalSignature sig = new PrivateKeySignature(authnPrivateKey,  "SHA1", "BeIDProvider");

        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, sig, keyStore.getCertificateChain("Signature"), null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }
```

I have basically constructed this code together using trial and error. I have gotten it so that I can actually put my signature on the PDF (after unlocking my signing certificate by inputting the PIN), but when I open the PDF, it tells me the signature is invalid. I can see my name on the signature, but when I try to validate it in Adobe Reader, I am greeted with the error **0x2726**

There must be something I am doing wrong, but I have not been able to find the definitive reason.

Comment: Can you share a sample signed file? That been asked I think itext 5.5.10 was built using a different bouncy castle version. Have you tried matching the versions?

Comment: I have tried to e-mail signed pdfs to you on the e-mailaddress you supplied in your stackoverflow profile

Comment: iText uses BouncyCastle 1.49. And I think there is already a project to sign pdf files with the beid, I'll look it up when I'm at the office.

Comment: @arnehehe I received your mail and am looking into it but you should really try the proposal from pedrofb's answer, it appears very plausible.

Comment: I downgraded my project to using BouncyCastle 1.49. Using Pedrofb's fix I ended up being able to sign the pdf correctly with both 1.49 and 1.55. I will continue to use 1.49, but felt it was worth mentioning for this particular case both 1.49 and 1.55 worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `keyStore.getKey("Authentication", null)` to get the key and `keyStore.getCertificateChain("Signature")` to get the certification chain. Seems your card has two certificates. Then the public key of `Signature` certificate will not match private key of `Authentication` certificate

Try to replace `PrivateKey authnPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("Authentication", null);` with

```
PrivateKey authnPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("Signature", null);
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you.